# Postgres - Finding an open cursor and closing it

Tags: postgresql

In `SQL Server` I used following SQL to find an open cursor and closing it in a 'catch' block.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID) WHERE [name] = 'Crsr_IDs' AND IS_OPEN = 1)
BEGIN
    CLOSE Crsr_IDs
    DEALLOCATE Crsr_IDs
END
```

In similar way how to find an open cursor in `Postgres` with specific name in EXCEPTION block and close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pg_cursors` table with list of opened cursors:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pg_cursors WHERE name = 'Crsr_IDs) THEN
  CLOSE Crsr_IDs;
END IF;
```

But usually it is not necessary - if cursor was opened in protected block - `BEGIN EXCEPTION WHEN END`, then handler of exception closes opened cursors automatically.

Comment: Thanks!! I have checked if cursor is still open in exception block by adding RAISE EXCEPTION after opening cursor and adding IF EXISTS as you suggested and it is never found opened. So I don't add IF EXISTS condition also as the cursor is automatically closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`pg_cursors`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-cursors.html) catalog to query for open cursors in your session, but be aware that some of the cursors might have been opened by the system.

Usually you use [`CLOSE ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-close.html) to close all open cursors.

Comment: How this could be written in ESQL/C? I tried with no luck: `EXEC SQL IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pg_cursors WHERE name = :cur) THEN CLOSE :cur;`. And how expensive is this in an application to check for open cursors from time to time.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, you would have to use C's `if`. It would be better to write your code so that cursors are closed as soon as you are done with them.

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume that PL/pgSQL is used, and a cursor is assigned to a variable.

If you need to close a cursor if it is open, you can just execute CLOSE (see [Using Cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING)), and catch exceptions which can happen. For example:

```
do $$
declare 
  Crsr_IDs refcursor = 'Crsr_IDs'; 
begin 
  begin 
    close Crsr_IDs; 
  exception 
    when invalid_cursor_name or null_value_not_allowed then null; 
  end; 
end; 
$$;
```

Explanations:
CLOSE can raise exceptions in some conditions which we expect to happen.

Possible conditions:

invalid_cursor_name - there is no open cursor with the assigned name. Either the cursor is already closed, or it was not open at all.

null_value_not_allowed - the cursor variable is null. It could be not initialized at all, and the cursor name was not assigned to it.

See [PostgreSQL Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

See [Trapping Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).